latexmk cannot create source code subfolders when compiling to a different target directory

This question is similar to latexmk -outdir with \include, but there are updates in @John Collins's answer.

I have a LaTeX project (https://github.com/batchor/hcmut-thesis) with main file thesis.tex which includes several .tex files in a subfolder.
My project structure:
├── chapters
│   ├── back
│   │   ├── design-docs.tex
│   │   └── test-suite.tex
│   ├── front
│   │   ├── abstract.tex
│   │   ├── acknowledge.tex
│   │   └── declaration.tex
│   └── main
│       ├── eval.tex
│       ├── methodology.tex
│       ├── overview.tex
│       └── sys-design.tex
├── graphics
│   └── hcmut.png
├── hcmut-thesis.cls
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.txt
├── refs
│   └── example.bib
└── thesis.tex

thesis.tex includes several tex files:
% thesis.tex
\include{chapters/front/declaration.tex}
\include{chapters/front/acknowledge.tex}
\include{chapters/front/abstract.tex}

Then I compile the prokect with latexmk -cd -jobname=output -auxdir=/tmp/test -outdir=/tmp/test -synctex=1 -interaction=batchmode -f -pdf thesis.tex, and I got the error:
Latexmk: Missing input file 'chapters/front/declaration.aux' (or dependence on it) from following:
  'No file chapters/front/declaration.aux.'
Latexmk: Couldn't create directory '/tmp/test/chapters/front'.
    System error: 'No such file or directory'

I know the problem is that latexmk coundn't duplicate the folder structure in the targete dir /tmp/test. How can I fix it and let latexmk automatically duplicate the folder structure in the target directory?
Currently I'm using this workaround to duplicate the folder structure before executing latemk:
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p /tmp/test/{} \;


Welcome to TeX.SE!

Unfortunately your workaround is the most practical method. Stick with it.

@user202729: This question is different because: (a) It involves 2 levels of subdirectory instead of 1. (b) The answers to the old question you refer to are out-of-date.  (I've made an update to my answer there.)  See my answer for more details.

@JohnCollins For readers' convenience, it seems the most convenient to direct them to the old question. Now there is the updated information there anyway (because you updated your answer)

This is a bug in latexmk. When there is more one level of subdirectory in the file specified to \include, as in
\include{chapters/front/declaration.tex}

latexmk does not create the necessary subdirectory chapters/front of the aux dir.  This is in contrast to the situation where only one level of subdirectory is involved, as in
\include{chapters/intro}

where latexmk does create the necessary subdirectory.  (That was implemented in v. 4.39.)
I've corrected this for the next release (4.86).

I couldn't believe the latexmk author was here answering user questions! I will stick with my current workaround and wait for the new release. Thank you!
